# Can't connect to Google Cloud SQL using socket, but can do so using the IP address

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an existing PHP service running on a Compute Engine VM Instance and a Google Cloud SQL service.

After I login to the VM and run this command

```
mysql -h <IP> <db> -umyuser -p
```

I can connect to the mysql instance with no problem.

However, if I try to use socket

```
mysql -h localhost --socket=/home/forge/.gcp/cloudsql/proxy/socket/project:region:production
```

I get this error

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 95
```

This is an existing setup and I am not very familiar with GCP. But, this was working until yesterday after which it started to fail with this error

Did I miss any configuration change?

Comment: when you connect through IP, are you using the Public or a Private IP? Sometimes this happens when there are some firewall rules that may block the traffic.

Comment: I am using the public IP

Comment: Do you have any firewall rules set up in the project, or are they in different vpc networks?